# Selecting an optgroup title as an option

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, webkit, hierarchy

I have a tree of data organized like so (but with many many more options) in a dropdown list:

```
 pizza
   pizza.mediterranean
   pizza.veggie
   pizza.meatlover
 drinks
   drinks.soda
     drinks.soda.pepsi
     drinks.soda.coke
   drinks.beer
   drinks.water
```

I want the larger categories (pizza,drinks) to show up as optgroups but I want to be able to select an optgroup as an option in the drop down list.  What I have read multiple places is that optgroups are only for grouping and can not be selected.

Since I also want more than one level of indentation to allow the dropdown to look as close to the above example as possible -- perhaps optgroups aren't the way to go but rather a css solution.  In firefox I can do what I want by adding styles to the options and making them bold and/or have a left padding but it seems like in webkit the only attibute I can change on options in a dropdown is their color.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this effect in webkit (chrome/safari) and firefox --- (I don't really care about IE at the moment) using optgroups, css, or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to go low-tech:

```
<select>
<option>Root</option>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Second level</option>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Third level</option>
</select>
```

You are hitting the limits of what you can do with a real select.  Conceptually, these select widgets are drawn by the OS  (although some browsers - firefox - have their own implementations), so the styling options are limited.

There are many nice select replacements.  The one I'm most familiar with is jqueryui's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).  It is fast and flexible and you can style the options however you like.  One can imagine other home-grown solutions using jquery or another toolkit - or plain 'ol javascript.

Comment: That is the surefire way to get it to work on all browsers, but it doesn't allow for any styling to make things bold like an optgroup does...

Answer (score 1):

Using a set of radio buttons (or checkboxes, if several choices are to be allowed) instead of a `select` element, you can organize and style them like any other content, e.g. with indentation and bolding. It won’t act as a dropdown menu, though, but this can actually be a usability and accessibility improvement.